InnoSetup - Elapsed/Remaining Time & Percentage of decompression with unarc.dll
i got a question, it is possible to show elapsed/remaining time and percentage of decompression with unarc.dll ?
If yes, how ?
Cordially
I tried to search online but i got no replies about unarc.dll and showing this type of values.

@MartinPrikryl i tried that but i got only a progress bar, not what i asked in the question.

Well, the progress bar is difficult part. It was you job to find this question yourself. And if you are not able to do the easy part of calculating the times based on progress, you can now ask a question on that. Your question does not show any effort on your side.
